# Grid Control in WPF Browser Application

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I am using WPF Browser Application. This is my .xaml for both my pages. So how do i pass the "grid1" from page 1 to my "grid2" in page 2??

In Page 1.....

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid Height="156" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,96,0,0" 
              Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" removed="Aqua">
            <Label Content="heart" Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Margin="86,74,0,0" Name="label1" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Width="57" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In page 2....

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid Height="156" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,90,0,0" Name="grid2"          
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You mean passing the data or the Grid object ?

Comment: Passing the whole grid with its content to another grid in another page.